# Closing form with X much slower then taskbar close

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, formclosing, windows-xp-sp2

One of our customers is using Windows XP with SP2. When they close a form using the normal X button on the form it takes around 30 seconds for the form to be closed. However when they right click on the form in the windows taskbar and click on close it closes straight away.

I've stepped through the program on my dev machine running both scenarios and the same events are being called in my code, so I am not sure what the difference is between these 2 methods of closing a form.

We have other customers running XP but they're using SP3. Is this an issue with windows, should I just get them to upgrade to SP3?

The program is written in C# using .Net 3.5

Comment: What code exactly runs when closing the window?  Can you reproduce the slow closes in your environment (e.g. VM running XP SP2)?